# Why did Game 1 of the 2015 ALDS have a start time that depended on another game?

Tags: baseball, mlb

Game 1 of the ALDS Blue Jays Game this past Thursday was set to begin at either 3:37 p.m. and 4:07 p.m. (depending on who won the Yankees-Astros wildcard game). Why were there two start times?

Comment: Why the later start, if the Yankees had won?

Answer (score 5):

Likely, the [Houston Texans game Thursday night](http://www.sbnation.com/nfl/2015/10/8/9472777/texans-colts-2015-preview-thursday-night-football) was the reason.  That game stated at 8:25 ET, and while baseball games usually take three hours or so, most likely they wanted a bit of extra time to ensure fans can watch both games.

Comment: Thanks. That is definitely a possibility. I have sent an email to MLB but I have yet to hear from them.

Answer (score 0):

The Astros also had a game that night. A friend of mine has just made me aware of this fact. Blue Jays v Rangers would start at 3:37 and the Astros v Royals had a 7:37 start. This is more likely to be the answer.  Overlapping MLB games (for teams) in the same state during playoffs is likely what they were trying to avoid.

Still waiting to hear from mlb though.
Thanks for your help.